# Required output generated for json data

Tags: php, html, json

```
{"99.net":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"dotnet"},
"99.org":  {"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domorg"},
"99.mobi":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"dotmobi"},
"99.name":{"status":"Invalid Domain Name","classkey":"dotname"},
"99.us":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domus"},
"99.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},
"99.info":{"status":"Invalid Domain Name","classkey":"dominfo"},
"99.co.uk":{"status":"available","classkey":"thirdleveldotuk"},
"99.biz":{"status":"Invalid Domain Name","classkey":"dombiz"},
"99.in":{"status":"Invalid Domain Name","classkey":"dotin"}}
```

I'm able to display the output with the following code:

```
$json1 = json_decode($response1);

 foreach($json1 as $key=>$sel_rows)     
  {
      echo $key ;
      echo " status: ". $sel_rows->status."&nbsp;";
      echo " Class: ". $sel_rows->classkey."&nbsp;";
      echo "Price";
      echo "<br>";                                             
  }<br>
```

Now, I need to sort it so that a table such as the following can be shown:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>.com</td>
<td>.net</td>
<td>.info</td>
<td>.org</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="">ADD</a></td>
<td><a href="">ADD</a></td>
<td><a href="">ADD</a></td>
<td><a href="">ADD</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to sort the response in a way that I can use to generate this table, using the response data to add tool tips to the ADD links (like dinakar.com).

Comment: If you want to use JSON decoded data as array, you need to pass TRUE as second argument of json_decode() function.

Comment: If you want a tooltip, put the domain in the `title` attribute of the `A` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not having a problem decoding the response, but rather normalizing it for what you need to display. To do that, you'll need to extract the TLD from the domain string, unless you *know* it ahead of time. Presumably you do, as it was used to request the response to begin with?

Anyway, the following code illustrates one way of getting it into an array suitable for you to pass to your view (or however you're doing it):

```
$response1 = <<< EOF
{"99.net":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"dotnet"},
"99.org":  {"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domorg"},
"99.mobi":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"dotmobi"},
"99.name":{"status":"Invalid Domain Name","classkey":"dotname"},
"99.us":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domus"},
"99.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},
"99.info":{"status":"Invalid Domain Name","classkey":"dominfo"},
"99.co.uk":{"status":"available","classkey":"thirdleveldotuk"},
"99.biz":{"status":"Invalid Domain Name","classkey":"dombiz"},
"99.in":{"status":"Invalid Domain Name","classkey":"dotin"}}
EOF;


function get_tld($url) {
    $host = parse_url($url);
    $domain = $host['path'];
    $tail = substr($domain, -7); // Watch out, gotcha! Be sure of this.
    $tld = strstr($tail, ".");
    return $tld;
}

$domains = array();
$json1 = json_decode($response1);

foreach ($json1 as $idx => $obj) {
    $tld = get_tld($idx);
    $domains[$tld] = array('tld' => $tld, 'status' => $obj->status, 'classkey' => $obj->classkey);
}
```

This is off the top of my head. The resulting `$domains` array looks like this (truncated for brevity):

```
Array
(
    [.net] => Array
        (
            [tld] => .net
            [status] => regthroughothers
            [classkey] => dotnet
        )

    [.org] => Array
        (
            [tld] => .org
            [status] => regthroughothers
            [classkey] => domorg
        )
```

Note, I'm not doing a whole lot of sanity here, but that should be enough to help you sink your teeth into it. You'd then just make your table head off the keys, and populate your add links with whatever information they need that was returned in the response.

Answer (score 2):

```
$json1 = json_decode($response1, TRUE);

 foreach($json1 as $key=>$sel_rows)     
  {
      echo $key ;
      echo " status: ". $sel_rows['status']."&nbsp;";
      echo " Class: ". $sel_rows['classkey']."&nbsp;";
      echo "Price";
      echo "<br>";                                             
  }
```

Comment: if we use the true in the json_decode then status and classkey values are empty

Comment: I misread the question too. He's not having a problem decoding the data, what he wants is to get the TLD out of `$key` and sort the results using it.

Comment: yes i want the Tld out of the $key and sort according to the TLD, please help with the code and we need to show when we placed the cursor on the Add button with the $key value